# What's the correct way to handle complex objects with Restangular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

In the app on which I'm working I use a REST API with 
Angular 1 on the frontend. I use the `extendModel` function of Restangular in order to initialize the data that I receive. During the initialization phase I create a lot of cross-references and the object becomes cyclic. Here comes my problem. In order to `put` or `post` my data back to the server I have to either copy the object by picking just the fields that I need or I can work on the same object and delete all the references that I created and restore them when I get a response from the server. I feel like these 2 options kinda go head-to-head with the intended usage of Restangular. Is there a better way to do this?